# JavaScript window.scroll vs. window.scrollTo?

Tags: javascript

Any idea what, if any, difference there is between `window.scroll(x, y)` and `window.scrollTo(x, y)` [not talking about jQuery]?

Also any ideas as to which browsers support which?
Thanks

Answer (score 89, accepted):

There are no differences: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scroll

As far as I know, all major browsers support both.

Comment: These are now in a draft specification: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#widl-Window-scroll-void-long-x-long-y, they are all supported in the spec to maintain backwards compatibility

Comment: If they are the same, then why are there two different functions?

Comment: The authoritative answer is [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-window-scrollto): *When the scrollTo() method is invoked, the user agent must act as if the scroll() method was invoked with the same arguments.*

Comment: well, .scroll only went half way up the page, and .scrollTo worked, maybe it is chrome or iframe issue, anyways, bad, maybe use both .scroll and .scrollTo

Comment: Edge doesn't seem to like either scroll() or scrollTo(), at least on divs. You can still set the value of scrollTop though.

Comment: Actually, `scroll()` 'scrolls the window to a particular place in the document' and `scrollTo()` 'scrolls to a particular set of coordinates in the document' ;)

Comment: The Mozilla documentation seems to be wrong regarding the Options method of scroll() and scrollTo(). It says: "Top: Specifies the number of pixels along the Y axis to scroll the window or element.". And similarly for Left. This looks like a copy/paste from ScrollBy() error. I think it should be: "Top: Specifies the pixel along the horizontal axis that you want displayed in the upper left".

Answer (score 13):

`Window.scrollTo()` is effectively the same as the `window.scroll(x,y)` method. For scrolling a particular distance, use `Window.scrollBy()`.

Also see `Window.scrollByLines()`, `Window.scrollByPages()` and `Element.scrollIntoView()`

MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

Answer (score 7):

In the absence of deprecation, I prefer `window.scroll` instead of `window.scrollTo`:

- [The specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-window-scrollto) only describes `window.scrollTo` by referring to `window.scroll`, suggesting that `window.scroll` is authoritative.
- `window.scroll` has ~3M search results; `window.scrollTo` has ~0.5M.

Answer (score 1):

There is [scrollTo, scroll, and scrollBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536728(VS.85).aspx)! Apparently there is no standard covering this functionality so all Browsers may not implement it the same.

Comment: `scrollBy` is unlike the others in that it scrolls relative to the current position.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I did not know that and the MDC does not state it

Comment: These are now in a draft specification: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#widl-Window-scroll-void-long-x-long-y, they are all supported in the spec to maintain backwards compatibility

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with this and scrollBy was just what I needed!