# How to jump to top of browser page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I'm writing a modal popup and I need the browser to jump to the top of the screen when the open modal button is pressed. Is there a way to scroll the browser to the top using jQuery?

Answer (score 456, accepted):

You can set the `scrollTop`, like this:

```
$('html,body').scrollTop(0);
```

Or if you want a little animation instead of a snap to the top:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
```

Comment: good one... I've used scrollTo plugin for jQuery before to accomplish this - could've saved a bit of code with your code... thanks for the lesson ;-)

Comment: @MikhailBatcer - disable your CSS and then see if it works. You might have an issue with how you've styled your `html` and `body` tags. otherwise use `$(window)` instead.

Comment: how to add duration for animation-skrolling?

Answer (score 159):

Without animation, you can use plain JS:

```
scroll(0,0)
```

With animation, check [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147118/2571620).

Comment: Is this supported in all browsers?

Comment: `scroll` is in the CSSOM standard while `scrollTo` was originally defined in DOM Level 0 and not part of any standard. However, CSSOM includes `scrollTo` for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I think `scroll` is widely supported. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1925671/41906

Comment: Thanks. I guess `window && window.scroll(0,0);` is acceptable in my view model.

Answer (score 43):

If you're using jQuery UI dialog, you could just style the modal to appear with the position fixed in the window so it doesn't pop-up out of view, negating the need to scroll.  Otherwise,

```
var scrollTop = function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 13):

You could do it without javascript and simply use anchor tags? Then it would be accessible to those js free.

although as you are using modals, I assume you don't care about being js free. ;)

Comment: Using anchor tags would interrupt hash-based navigation.

Answer (score 10):

Vanilla **Javascript** solution

```
theId.onclick = () => window.scrollTo({top: 0})
```

If you want smooth scrolling

```
theId.onclick = () => window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
   
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
 
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll Down</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible when the user starts to scroll the page.</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but for those having problems in Edge:

Plain JS: `window.scrollTop=0;`

Unfortunately, `scroll()` and `scrollTo()` throw errors in Edge.

Answer (score 3):

As a couple responses hinted at, I had to use `window.scrollTo(0,0);` instead of `scrollTo(0,0);`

`window.scrollTo(0,0);` works with pure javascript in all browsers tested (no animation). ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)) ([w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp)).

**Examples from MDN:**

Without options:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Using options:

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

---

Here's a simple example using javascript inline with the html:

```
<button onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 0);">Click to scroll to top</button>
```

With smooth scrolling:

```
<button onclick="window.scrollTo({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});">Smooth scroll</button>
```

*Note:

It seems smooth scrolling isn't working by default in Chrome (e.g. in version 89) without first enabling

**chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling***

---

*`window.scroll(0,0);` seems similar to `window.scrollTo(0,0);` but with less compatibility for options. ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll)).*

Answer (score 1):

you're using jQuery UI dialog, you could just style the modal to appear with the position fixed in the window so it doesn't pop-up out of view, negating the need to scroll. Other