# Scroll to top animation in pure javascript? Can't use jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an easy way to convert this:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 10000);
```

into pure javascript?  I need to be able to run the js in a setting where I don't have jQuery available.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Check some of the answers (not the accepted one). http://stackoverflow.com/a/4147160/752527

Comment: @HanletEscaño That question specifically uses jQuery. OP is not using jQuery.

Comment: Does this need to animate on iOS 7 and below?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by incrementally changing the [scrollTop property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) over a period of time.

```js
var scrollingElement = document.body;
var endScrollPosition = scrollingElement.clientHeight;
var timeInMS = 10000;
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var endTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + timeInMS).getTime() - startTime;

// Use requestAnimationFrame to ensure a smooth transition
requestAnimationFrame(function animate() {
  // Determine what percentage of the total time has passed
  var now = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
  var ratio = now / endTime;
  if (ratio > 1) {
    ratio = 1;
  }
  
  scrollingElement.scrollTop = endScrollPosition * ratio;
  if (ratio < 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
});
```

```html
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
<h1>Padding</h1>
```