# Why JS doesn't want to scroll?

Tags: javascript

here is my code:

```
function trailer() {
    window.scroll(0,1750);
}
```

and the html

```
<li> <a href="#" onclick="trailer()">Trailer GTA 4</a></li>
```

..When I click on the link, it scrolls to (0,0) instead of scrolling to (0,1750)
why ???

Comment: Why not just link it to  the `div` in question? `<a href="#my-trailer">Jump to Trailer</a>`.

Comment: Because you're not stopping the event after your handler has finished his work: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7hhft35/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possible solutions, you can link the `ID` of the element in a `a` tag, as such,

**HTML Example**

```
<a href="#myDiv">Jump to DIV</a>

<div id="myDiv">DIV!</div>
```

**Example**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwps9mx4/0)

**You need to prevent the default behavior of the link by using `return false` or `event.preventDefault();`.**

The JavaScript alternative is to use [`scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo), though as @mplungjan has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925671/javascript-window-scroll-vs-window-scrollto) the difference between `scroll` and `scrollTo` is no difference.

Comment: Scroll and scrollTo does the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925671/javascript-window-scroll-vs-window-scrollto

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for that had no idea, will include that in the post.

Comment: The reason it does not work is he needs to return false or preventDefault

Comment: @mplungjan updated, thanks.