# How to scroll a webpage using selenium webdriver in Python without using javascript method execute_script()

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll, webdriver

I am trying to scroll a web page by using mouse and scroll bar. I am exploring any other option than

```
"driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 5000'))"
```

I did try options like chrome actions, however nothing seems to be working.
Would need some guidance if anyone has any idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your *usecase* is to `scroll()` the [window containing the DOM document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), there is no better way other then using the either of the following [Window Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#Methods):

- [Window.scrollBy()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy)
- [Window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

If your *usecase* is to `scroll()` an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) there is no better way other then using the [Element Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element#Methods):

- [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

> You can find a detailed discussion in [What is the difference between the different scroll options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681172/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-scroll-options/54689339#54689339)

---

However, if you want to avoid the `execute_script()` to interact with a *WebElement* you have two (2) other options available as follows:

- Using [move_to_element()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element) from [selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains). This method will automatically *scroll* the element within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).

  - Example code:

    ```
    menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav")
    hidden_submenu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav #submenu1")
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu).click(hidden_submenu).perform()
    ```
- Using [element_to_be_clickable()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) from [selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions). This **expected_conditions** when used in conjunction with [selenium.webdriver.support.wait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) will automatically *scroll* the element within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).

  - Example code:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Cart"))).click()
    ```

Comment: I had tried ActionChains but it is not giving me desired results. I was trying to scrape an intranet powerbi dashboard which has different sections all in iframe which can be scrolled. But thanks for your excellent answer.

Comment: `move_to_element()` doesn't seem to work properly in Firefox or geckodriver due to [this (geckodriver issue #776)](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/776).

This may be the cause of the issue if you're using geckodriver.