# javascript error: arguments[0].scrollIntoView is not a function using selenium on python

Tags: python, selenium, scroll

I'm using Selenium on python and I would like to scroll to an element to click on it. Everywhere I see that the rigth things to do to go directly to the element is to use :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('dg-button')
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

But I have this error : "javascript error: arguments[0].scrollIntoView is not a function".

What to I do wrong ? Thanks

Comment: change to `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)` and let me know

Comment: I have the exact same error

Comment: are you importing `from selenium import webdriver` this ?

Comment: What browser are you using? try update it and the driver.

Comment: I'm using this `from selenium import webdriver` on python 2.7

Comment: @JulienThillard Update the question with the error stack trace

Comment: and this one `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)`

Comment: Ok I was going to a wrong element... and this one working `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the line of code mentioned below instead of the one you are using:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

**Updated answer:**
You can also use `location_once_scrolled_into_view` it gives the coordinates of the element but it does scrolls the element into view as well. You can use it like:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('dg-button')
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Comment: @JulienThillard have updated my answer, please check the updated answer

Comment: Ok I was going to a wrong element... and this one working driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

Answer (score 3):

[`scrollIntoView()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681172/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-scroll-options/54689339#54689339) is part of the DOM API and you need to run it on an *WebElement* but not on a *List* of *WebElement(s)*.

You need to change `find_element(s)` to `find_element`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('dg-button')
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use it on a List of elements, than you can override it with Python, so you can navigate to the element that you want

e.g. first element of a List

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('dg-button')
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element[0])
```

e.g. last element of a List

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('dg-button')
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element[-1])
```

Hope that it helps :)