# Selenium how to scroll down to get all the link

Tags: python, selenium

I want to export all the documents, so I need all the links.

if the mouse does not scroll down, all links will not be loaded.

[image: quip]

Need to move down a bit to gradually load

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Configuration information
email = "187069474@qq.com"
password = "Huangbo1019@"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
index_url = "https://testselenium.quip.com/BCWAOAUkg1v"
driver.get(url=index_url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-nav-collapse"]/ul/li[9]/a').click()  # click login
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/input').send_keys(email)  # input email
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email-submit"]').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/form/div/input[2]').send_keys(password)  # input password
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/form/button').click()
time.sleep(2)
```

May need a new strategy

Comment: check this post on how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python

Comment: hi,I tested it, but it didn't work.

Comment: I am getting upto 29 links.Not all :(

Answer (score 0):

you can try directly with request library

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for link in links:
    try:
        requests.get(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to scroll by coordinates. If you can get the height of your page in pixels, you can call a `Scroll(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate)` method & increment the scroll coordinates with each successive scroll.

You want to start by scrolling to an initial x,y coordinate on the page. As you scroll down, your y coordinate to scroll to will change. If you don't increment the y coordinate as you scroll down, you will be stuck scrolling to the same place over and over again. So you should determine your `increment` variable based on the pixel height of the page you are using. Depending on how many rows you want to scroll at once, your `increment` variable should be about equal to the pixel height of each 'row' you are scrolling past.

`numberOfScrolls` should be equal to the number of rows which you wish to scroll.

A method would look something like this:

```
public void ScrollDown(int startX, int startY, int increment, int numberOfScrolls) 
{
    // cast webdriver to javascript executor
    var executor = ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver);

    // keep track of current y coordinate
    // since we are scrolling down, y coordinate will change with each scroll
    var currentYCoordinate = startY;

    // scroll down in a loop
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfScrolls; i++)
    {
        // scroll down
        executor.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(startX, currentYCoordinate);");

        // todo: implement any FindElement methods to get the new elements which have been scrolled into view.

        // update y coordinate since we just scrolled down
        currentYCoordinate = currentYCoordinate + increment;

     }
}
```