# Python Selenium check all checkboxes on page

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to tick all checkboxes on a page. There are about 50 of them and this code seems to work but only ticks what is visible on the screen. It doesn't scroll down the table and tick the remaining boxes.

```
def select_checkbox():
    checkboxes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("//input[@type='checkbox']")
    for checkbox in checkboxes:
        if not checkbox.is_selected():
            checkbox.click() # to tick it
```

I'm thinking It's only finding those on the screen as the rest are still loading. I need to wait until all checkboxes have loaded but I'm not sure about how to go about this. Any help is appreciated.

Below is the table row

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="admin_contract_form[price_forms_attributes][51][offered]" id="admin_contract_form_price_forms_attributes_51_offered">
```

Comment: Did you wait for the page to load and did you get all the checkboxes. You can check by print(len(checkboxes)). I would also use webdriver wait to allow all the elements to load in. Also what url are you testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explicit waits `presence_of_all_elements_located` for all the checkboxes.

Also, to scroll `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", checkbox)` this will likely to get the job done.

**Code:**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
def select_checkbox():
    checkboxes = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='checkbox']")))
    for checkbox in checkboxes:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", checkbox)
        if not checkbox.is_selected():
            checkbox.click() # to tick it
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for assistance. I'm currently getting this message when attempting to run the code.             Element <input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="1" name="admin_contract_form[price_forms_attributes][0][offered]" id="admin_contract_form_price_forms_attributes_0_offered"> is not clickable at point (1466, 6). Other element would receive the click: <div ui-header="">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.93)

Comment: It is saying `<input disabled="disabled"`, was it visible on UI when you ran the script? Also please maximize the screen size and see it that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the desired [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631116/python-selenium-wait-for-several-elements-to-load/64770041#64770041) and [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) the individual checkboxes inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) as follows:

```
def select_checkbox():
    checkboxes = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//input[starts-with(@name, 'admin_contract_form') and starts-with(@id, 'admin_contract_form_price_forms_attributes') and not(@disabled)]")))
    for checkbox in checkboxes:
        if not checkbox.is_selected():
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(checkbox)).click()
```

> PS: *`click()`* inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) will [scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681172/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-scroll-options/54689339#54689339) the  element into the view by default.

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I get a timeout exception when I run this. The page sits there and doesn't tick anything?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: When I call the function, same thing happens. Page sits there and doesn't check anything. Times out. 
    checkboxes = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//input[starts-with(@name, 'admin_contract_form') and starts-with(@id, 'admin_contract_form_price_forms_attributes') and not(@disabled)]")))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: